# Measuring the current by Pearson CT

Tags: rf

I am trying to measure the discharge current of my system by a Pearson CT, and even though the input impedance of the CT is 50 Ω, it is instructed in FAQs of the Pearson electronics to use a high impedance oscilloscope.
Now I have two questions:

1. If I intend to use an attenuator to protect my scope, should I use a high impedance attenuator or a 50 Ω?
2. Using a high impedance scope with a 50 Ω Pearson CT wouldn't cause a mismatch and result in doubling my output signal?

Comment: A datasheet for the transformer, and a diagram of your intended use will get you better answers.

Comment: Some CTs have the resistor inside the CT and some you must add it. Because I don't know the part number I cannot help much more.

Comment: It's an old wide band Pearson CT model No 1000, the data sheet can't be found online in their website anymore, however the internal resistance is 50 ohm I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot locate a datasheet, or an old catalog or something, you will need to measure the parameters yourself.

1. Measure its output impedance, using a function generator and BNC tee, effectively measuring return loss.  Convert the measurements into port impedance.  Preferably use a return loss bridge to measure this directly, but anything is fine as long as you can determine the impedance.
2. Measure its gain, using a test current pulse (say, a 1V supply into a 1Ω resistor, switched by a NE555 + transistor).  Also note how gain changes with load resistance (high-Z vs. 50Ω terminated, say).

Most likely, output impedance is a flat 50Ω and applying a termination merely reduces gain by half.  Bandwidth may be affected, which is something else to check.

The most important thing is if there's an internal burden resistor or not (or any other resistances e.g. attenuator).

Comment: I found out that the Pearson output resistance is 50 ohm, my question might be trivial to you but please help me, if I want to connect the output of my Pearson to a 50 ohm attenuator and then connect it to a high Z scope will my expected value increased by 2? I could I calculate the current from my Pearson given the Pearson sensitivity and attenuation factor.